# The SELECT permission was denied on the object '<Table_Name>', database '<Database_Name>', schema 'dbo'. - ASP.NET/SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a database "Sample". And there is a user in Active Directory (AD) called "CORPHQ\King". I have followed these steps:

```
1) Go to SQL Server Management Studio (2005) and "Security -> Logins".
2) Right Click -> New Login
3) Login Name : CORPHQ\King
4) Selected "Windows Authentication"
5) Default database - "Sample".
6) Under "User Mapping" section, Selected the "Sample" database, User as "CORPHQ\King" and selected "dbo" as default schema.
7) Selected "db_owner" as "Database role membership for - Sample".
```

Now in the WEB.CONFIG of the ASP.NET application, i do have:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DB" connectionString="Data Source=128.127.126.25; database=Sample; user=corphq\King; password=XXXXXXXXXXX; Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Now when i ran the ASP.NET application, i am getting the error mentioned:

```
Error:

The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'tbl_Student', database 'Sample', schema 'dbo'
```

I think so user "CORPHQ\King" has the "db_owner" access to "Sample" database. Am i correct ? Where am i missing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're specifying `Integrated Security` in your connection string, you shouldn't be specifying a username and password when using Windows Authentication.

Instead, you will be authenticating as whatever domain account ASP.NET is running under, which is probably the network service account.

Your application is likely connecting as a totally different user than `CORPHQ\King`, and this other login doesn't have the permissions for this operation.

For more details, see [How To: Connect to SQL Server Using Windows Authentication in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647396.aspx)

Comment: I did remove the "Integrated Security" in the connection string, then i am getting "Login Failed" error.

Comment: @user1054625 That's because without "Integrated Security", you're now using Sql Authentication instead of Windows Authentication... and since your login is setup on the Sql Server as Windows Authentication, you'll get that login error.  If you would like to use Windows Authentication, you'll want to figure out what domain account your application is using, and then grant that account access to your Sql Server... or if you want to use Sql Authentication, create a login on Sql Server for this purpose.

Comment: I have created an account in SQL Server. And placed the same in WEB.CONFIG - now it is working fine - Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may have given it access to connect to the database, but there should be further steps to GRANT the user specific permissions such as SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE on tables in that database.

Comment: Is there any T-SQL for granting (SELECT / INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE) on all those tables / stored procs in that DB at one shot ?

Comment: [Members of the db_owner fixed database role can perform all configuration and maintenance activities on the database.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180977(v=sql.90).aspx)  This includes `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE`.

Comment: Error - Incorrect syntax near '\: GRANT SELECT ON tbl_Student TO CORPHQ\King

Comment: Tried this also but no luck - Incorrect syntax near 'CORPHQ\King': GRANT SELECT ON tbl_Student TO 'CORPHQ\King'

Answer (score 1):

Solution is for this problem is that open the dbo schema 
Go to property and click on View database permission link.
Give the database select ,delete edit permission to DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$. user.